# Cakephp 2.x find query having DISTINCT and COUNT together on same field

Tags: mysql, cakephp, join, count, distinct

`User` table structure.

```
+------+-------+
|  id  | data  |
+------+-------+
|  1   |   a   |
+------+-------+
|  1   |   b   |
+------+-------+
|  2   |   c   |
+------+-------+
```

Desired result.

```
+------+-------+
|  id  | count |
+------+-------+
|  1   |   2   |
+------+-------+
|  2   |   1   |
+------+-------+
```

I tried DISTINCT and COUNT in many ways but still not getting desired result.

What i am trying

```
$this->User->find('all',array(
'conditions'=> array(),
'fields' => array(
'DISTINCT(User.id)',
'COUNT(DISTINCT User.id) as count'
)
)
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a group by clause

```
$this->User->find('all',
    array(
        'fields' => array(
            'User.id',
            'COUNT(User.id) as count'
        ),
        'group' => 'User.id'
    )
);
```

Comment: thanks a ton. Only problem is, it gives count in another array. I tried to change `count` to `User.count`  but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Bill's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39129009/1753837), to get `count` as a `User` field you need to get it as a `virtualField`

```
$this->User->virtualFields['count'] = 0;

$this->User->find('all', [
    'fields' => array(
        'User.id',
        'COUNT(User.id) as User__count'
    ),
    'group' => 'User.id'
]);
```

This would be your example's result:

```
########## DEBUG ##########
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'User' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'count' => '2'
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'User' => array(
            'id' => '2',
            'count' => '1'
        )
    )
)
###########################
```